# Debugging/fixing a BFS algorithm

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

*I'm solving this BFS homework problem, I believe the logic I'm following is right, but I got stuck in an implementation error I can't pinpoint. I'm looking for help debugging this solution, not proposing a new one.*

**Problem Statement:**

A kids has two robots that he controls remotely, both robots are on a NxN checkerboard and should be placed on the positions A and B in the checkerboard.

Both robots are affected by the remote controller simultaneously, the same command affects both of their states.

The remote controller can only make both robots turn clockwise or counterclockwise 90 degreees at a time or order both robots to move forward.

**Example:** 
The leftmost image shows the initial setting. The arrow pointing right is a robot facing east and the arraw pointing up is a robot facing north. Positions A and B are the robots destinies.

Center image shows the result of moving both robots one step forward.

Right image shows the result of making the robots rotate counterclockwise.

[image: Figure 1]

The kid desires to calculate the minimum number of movements necessary to take the robots from their initial positions to their destinies.

If a robot is commanded to run over a wall, it will remain on the same spot.

Both robots will remain on their original spot if they're commanded to move to the same spot.

Figure 2 shows this special cases.

[image]

Both robots should at arrive at a different destiny simultaneously.

**Input:**
Input consists of various test cases, the first line starts with an integer with the size N of the inputMatrix (the checkerboard), with 2<= N <=25.

The following N lines describe the checkerboard and have N characters each.

A '.' indicates an empty position.

N, E, S or O (Spanish for Oeste=West) indicates the original positiona and orientation of the robot.

D indicates a destiny for the robot in the checkerboard and '*' indicates an obstacle.

Input finishes with a case where N=0.

input.txt

```
5
D....
N...S
.....
*...*
....D
5
.....
S..S.
.....
.....
D..D.
3
SN.
***
.DD
0
```

correct output for input.txt:

```
8
3
-1
```

input2.txt:

```
5
.....
..D.S
.D...
.....
..N..
6
......
..S...
......
.ED...
......
.D....
11
....E......
....D......
...........
..S...D....
...........
...........
...........
...........
...........
...........
...........
13
.............
.............
.............
.............
.....N.......
.............
.........D...
..D..........
.............
...E.........
.............
.............
.............
25
...*.......*.*...........
........*..D...*.**....*.
*..*.*.........*..*..*..D
...*.**.*........*...*...
......**..*..***.***...**
.............*...........
....*...***.....*.**.....
......**.......**.*.*...*
.........*..*...*.*......
....**.*.*....**.*.*.*.*.
.......*............**...
..........*.*.....*......
...........**....*.**....
.....E.*.*..........**.*.
.........*.*.*.*..*..*...
*........**...*..........
................***..*...
........*....*....*...*..
......*...*.*...*.....**.
...*..........*.**.......
.**............*.*..*.*..
........*........*...*...
*......*..........*......
*...*......N*......*..*.*
.    .....*..*.*..*...*......
0
```

"correct" (?) output for input2.txt:

```
-1
-1
9
-1
46
```

My solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;




class Position {

    int i;
    int j;
    char orientation;

        Position() {

    }


    void setIJ(int i, int j){
        this.i=i;
        this.j=j;
    }

    void setOrientation(char c){

        orientation = c;
    }

   public boolean equals(Object o){

        if(o instanceof Position){

          Position p = (Position)o;
          if((p.i==this.i)&&(p.j==this.j)&&(p.orientation==this.orientation))
          {
              return true;
          }
              else return false;
          }

            return false;
   }

} //end class Position


class TransitionState {

    Position positionA;
    Position positionB;

    int counter;

    public boolean equals (Object o){

        if (o instanceof TransitionState){

          TransitionState transitionState= (TransitionState)o;

          if ((this.positionA.equals(transitionState.positionA))
                  &&(this.positionB.equals(transitionState.positionB)))
          {
              return true;
          }
        }
     return false;

    }

}


public class Robots {

static Position moveForward(Position oldPosition, int matrixSize, char orientation, char [][] inputMatrix){

     // add possible new Position
    Position newPosition= new Position();

    //first return oldPosition in border positions in which the robot shouldn't move

    if ((orientation=='O')&&(oldPosition.j==0))
           return oldPosition;

    if ((orientation=='E')&&(oldPosition.j==(matrixSize-1)))
           return oldPosition;

     if ((orientation=='N')&&(oldPosition.i==0))
           return oldPosition;

     if ((orientation=='S')&&(oldPosition.i==(matrixSize-1)))
           return oldPosition;


     if ((orientation=='O'))
         newPosition.setIJ(oldPosition.i, oldPosition.j-1);
     if ((orientation=='E'))
         newPosition.setIJ(oldPosition.i, oldPosition.j+1);
    if ((orientation=='S'))
         newPosition.setIJ(oldPosition.i-1, oldPosition.j);
    if ((orientation=='N'))
         newPosition.setIJ(oldPosition.i+1, oldPosition.j);


    //return oldPosition for positions in which the robot is blocked by *
    if (inputMatrix[newPosition.i][newPosition.j]=='*'){
        return oldPosition;
    }

    return newPosition; // if it got here, all ok

}


static char turnCounter (char orientation){

     if(orientation=='N')
         return 'O';
     if(orientation=='O')
         return 'S';
     if (orientation=='S')
         return 'E';
     else
         return 'N';

 }

static char turnClock(char orientation){

      if(orientation=='N')
         return 'E';
     if(orientation=='E')
         return 'S';
         if (orientation=='S')
         return 'O';
     else
         return 'N';

 }

static Position[] robotInitialPositions(char [][]inputMatrix){

     Position [] helperArray = new Position[2];

     int aux=0;

     for (int i=0; i<(inputMatrix[0].length); i++)
         for (int j=0; j<(inputMatrix[0].length); j++)
         {
            if((inputMatrix[i][j]=='N')||(inputMatrix[i][j]=='S')||(inputMatrix[i][j]=='O')||(inputMatrix[i][j]=='E'))
            {
                    helperArray[aux]= new Position();
                    helperArray[aux].setIJ(i, j);
                    if (inputMatrix[i][j]=='N'){helperArray[aux].orientation='N'; }
                    if (inputMatrix[i][j]=='S'){helperArray[aux].orientation='S'; }
                    if (inputMatrix[i][j]=='E'){helperArray[aux].orientation='E'; }
                    if (inputMatrix[i][j]=='O'){helperArray[aux].orientation='O'; }
                    aux= aux+1;
            }

         }

     return helperArray;

 }


static Position[] getDestinies(char [][]inputMatrix){

     Position [] helperArray = new Position[2];

     int aux=0;

     for (int i=0; i<(inputMatrix[0].length); i++)
         for (int j=0; j<(inputMatrix[0].length); j++)
         {
            if((inputMatrix[i][j]=='D'))
            {
                    helperArray[aux]= new Position();
                    helperArray[aux].i=i; helperArray[aux].j=j;
                    helperArray[aux].orientation='D';
                    aux=aux+1;

            }

         }

     return helperArray;

 }



static boolean [][]getUnvisitedMatrix(int matrixLength){


   boolean[][] unvisitedMatrix = new boolean [matrixLength][matrixLength];

    for (int i=0; i<matrixLength;i++)
        for (int j=0; j<matrixLength; j++)
            unvisitedMatrix[i][j]=false;

    return unvisitedMatrix;

}





static Position[]getNewRobotPositions (Position oldR1Pos,Position oldR2Pos, String movement, char [][]inputMatrix){

    Position[]newPositions = new Position[2];

    Position newR1Pos = new Position();
        Position newR2Pos = new Position();

    if(movement.equals("counter")){

        if (oldR1Pos.orientation=='N'){

            newR1Pos.orientation='O';

        }

        if (oldR1Pos.orientation=='S'){

            newR1Pos.orientation='E';

        }

        if (oldR1Pos.orientation=='E'){

            newR1Pos.orientation='N';

        }

        if (oldR1Pos.orientation=='O'){

            newR1Pos.orientation='S';
        }


        if (oldR2Pos.orientation=='N'){

            newR2Pos.orientation='O';
        }

        if (oldR2Pos.orientation=='S'){

            newR2Pos.orientation='E';

        }

        if (oldR2Pos.orientation=='E'){

            newR2Pos.orientation='N';

        }

        if (oldR2Pos.orientation=='O'){

            newR2Pos.orientation='S';

        }

        newR1Pos.i=oldR1Pos.i;
        newR1Pos.j=oldR1Pos.j;

        newR2Pos.i=oldR2Pos.i;
        newR2Pos.j=oldR2Pos.j;

        newPositions[0]=newR1Pos;
        newPositions[1]=newR2Pos;

//        System.out.println("MOVED COUNTERCLOCKWISE");
//        System.out.println("previous Robot 1 position was "+oldR1Pos.i + ","+oldR1Pos.j + " orientation was " + oldR1Pos.orientation +
//        " new Robot 1 position is " + newR1Pos.i + "," + newR1Pos.j+ " orientation is "+newR1Pos.orientation);
//
//        System.out.println("previous Robot 2 position was "+oldR2Pos.i + ","+oldR2Pos.j + " orientation was " + oldR2Pos.orientation +
//        " new Robot 2 position is " + newR2Pos.i + "," + newR2Pos.j+ " orientation is "+newR2Pos.orientation);

        return newPositions;


    }

    if(movement.equals("clock")){

        newR1Pos.i = oldR1Pos.i;
        newR1Pos.j = oldR1Pos.j;

        newR2Pos.i = oldR2Pos.i;
        newR2Pos.j = oldR2Pos.j;


        if (oldR1Pos.orientation=='N'){

             newR1Pos.orientation= 'E';
        }

        if (oldR1Pos.orientation=='S'){

             newR1Pos.orientation= 'O';
        }

        if (oldR1Pos.orientation=='E'){

             newR1Pos.orientation= 'S';
        }

        if (oldR1Pos.orientation=='O'){

             newR1Pos.orientation= 'N';

        }



        if (oldR2Pos.orientation=='N'){

             newR2Pos.orientation= 'E';
        }

        if (oldR2Pos.orientation=='S'){

             newR2Pos.orientation= 'O';

        }

        if (oldR2Pos.orientation=='E'){

             newR2Pos.orientation= 'O';

        }

        if (oldR2Pos.orientation=='O'){

             newR2Pos.orientation= 'N';

        }
//        System.out.println("MOVED CLOCKWISE");
//        System.out.println("previous Robot 1 position was "+oldR1Pos.i + ","+oldR1Pos.j + " orientation was " + oldR1Pos.orientation +
//        " new Robot 1 position is " + newR1Pos.i + "," + newR1Pos.j+ " orientation is "+newR1Pos.orientation);
/    /
//        System.out.println("previous Robot 2 position was "+oldR2Pos.i + ","+oldR2Pos.j + " orientation was " + oldR2Pos.orientation +
//        " new Robot 2 position is " + newR2Pos.i + "," + newR2Pos.j+ " orientation is "+newR2Pos.orientation);


        newPositions[0]=newR1Pos;
        newPositions[1]=newR2Pos;

        return newPositions;

    }

    if(movement.equals("forward")){

        //default case, if conditions not satisfied
        newR1Pos.i=oldR1Pos.i;
        newR1Pos.j=oldR1Pos.j;
            newR1Pos.orientation = oldR1Pos.orientation;

        newR2Pos.i=oldR2Pos.i;
        newR2Pos.j=oldR2Pos.j;
        newR2Pos.orientation = oldR2Pos.orientation; 


        if(oldR1Pos.orientation=='N'){

            if(oldR1Pos.i-1>=0){   //doesn't exceed the upper border

               //doesn't collide with '*'
               if (inputMatrix[oldR1Pos.i-1][oldR1Pos.j]!='*'){
                        newR1Pos.i=oldR1Pos.i-1;
                        newR1Pos.j=oldR1Pos.j;
                        newR1Pos.orientation = oldR1Pos.orientation;
               }

            }

        }

         if(oldR1Pos.orientation=='S'){

             if(oldR1Pos.i+1<inputMatrix.length){   //doesn't exceed the lower border

               //doesn't collide with '*'
               if (inputMatrix[oldR1Pos.i+1][oldR1Pos.j]!='*'){
                        newR1Pos.i=oldR1Pos.i+1;
                        newR1Pos.j=oldR1Pos.j;
                        newR1Pos.orientation = oldR1Pos.orientation;

               }
           }
        }

         if(oldR1Pos.orientation=='E'){

             if(oldR1Pos.j+1<inputMatrix.length){   //doesn't exceed the right border

               //doesn't collide with '*'
               if (inputMatrix[oldR1Pos.i][oldR1Pos.j+1]!='*'){
                        newR1Pos.i=oldR1Pos.i;
                        newR1Pos.j=oldR1Pos.j+1;
                        newR1Pos.orientation = oldR1Pos.orientation;
               }
           }

        }

        if(oldR1Pos.orientation=='O'){

             if(oldR1Pos.j-1>=0){   //doesn't exceed the left border

               //doesn't collide with '*'
               if (inputMatrix[oldR1Pos.i][oldR1Pos.j-1]!='*'){
                        newR1Pos.i=oldR1Pos.i;
                        newR1Pos.j=oldR1Pos.j-1;
                        newR1Pos.orientation = oldR1Pos.orientation;
               }

            }

        }

        //same for robot 2

       if(oldR2Pos.orientation=='N'){

            if(oldR2Pos.i-1>=0){   //doesn't exceed the upper border

               //doesn't collide with '*'
               if (inputMatrix[oldR2Pos.i-1][oldR2Pos.j]!='*'){
                        newR2Pos.i=oldR2Pos.i-1;
                        newR2Pos.j=oldR2Pos.j;
                        newR2Pos.orientation=oldR2Pos.orientation;
               }

            }

        }

         if(oldR2Pos.orientation=='S'){

             if(oldR2Pos.i+1<inputMatrix.length){   //doesn't exceed the lower border

               //doesn't collide with '*'
               if (inputMatrix[oldR2Pos.i+1][oldR2Pos.j]!='*'){
                        newR2Pos.i=oldR2Pos.i+1;
                        newR2Pos.j=oldR2Pos.j;
                        newR2Pos.orientation=oldR2Pos.orientation;
               }
           }
        }

         if(oldR2Pos.orientation=='E'){

             if(oldR2Pos.j+1<inputMatrix.length){   //doesn't exceed the right border

               //doesn't collide with '*'
               if (inputMatrix[oldR2Pos.i][oldR2Pos.j+1]!='*'){
                        newR2Pos.i=oldR2Pos.i;
                        newR2Pos.j=oldR2Pos.j+1;
                        newR2Pos.orientation=oldR2Pos.orientation;
               }
           }

        }

        if(oldR2Pos.orientation=='O'){

             if(oldR2Pos.j-1>=0){   //doesn't exceed the left border

               //doesn't collide with '*'
               if (inputMatrix[oldR2Pos.i][oldR2Pos.j-1]!='*'){
                        newR2Pos.i=oldR2Pos.i;
                        newR2Pos.j=oldR2Pos.j-1;
                        newR2Pos.orientation=oldR2Pos.orientation;
               }

            }

        }


        //if robots collide in new positions, revert to their original positions
        if ((newR1Pos.i==newR2Pos.i) && (newR1Pos.j==newR2Pos.j)){

            //revert robot 1 position
             newR1Pos.i=oldR1Pos.i;
             newR1Pos.j=oldR1Pos.j;
             newR1Pos.orientation = oldR1Pos.orientation;

             //revert robot 2 position
             newR2Pos.i=oldR2Pos.i;
             newR2Pos.j=oldR2Pos.j;
             newR2Pos.orientation = oldR2Pos.orientation;
        }

        newPositions[0] = newR1Pos;
        newPositions[1] = newR2Pos;

//        System.out.println("MOVED FORWARD");
//         System.out.println("previous Robot 1 position was "+oldR1Pos.i + ","+oldR1Pos.j + " orientation was " + oldR1Pos.orientation +
//        " new Robot 1 position is " + newR1Pos.i + "," + newR1Pos.j+ " orientation is "+newR1Pos.orientation);
//
//        System.out.println("previous Robot 2 position was "+oldR2Pos.i + ","+oldR2Pos.j + " orientation was " + oldR2Pos.orientation +
//        " new Robot 2 position is " + newR2Pos.i + "," + newR2Pos.j+ " orientation is "+newR2Pos.orientation);

    } //end movement.equals("forward")


    return newPositions;

}


//1  procedure BFS(Graph,source):
//2      create a queue Q
//3      enqueue source onto Q
//4      mark source
//5      while Q is not empty:
//6          dequeue an item from Q into v
//7          for each edge e incident on v in Graph:
//8              let w be the other end of e
//9              if w is not marked:
//10                 mark w
//11                 enqueue w onto Q



 static void BFS (char [][] inputMatrix){

    ArrayList<TransitionState> transitionStatesArray = new ArrayList<TransitionState>();

    int moveCounter=0; //turns and forward movements add here

    int tempMoveCounterRobot1=0; int tempMoveCounterRobot2=0;
    int maxMoveCounter=0;

    PositionsAndCounter positionsAndCounter= new PositionsAndCounter();

    Queue <PositionsAndCounter>queue = new LinkedList<PositionsAndCounter>();

    Position robotInitial[] = robotInitialPositions(inputMatrix); //get source
    positionsAndCounter.positionPair=robotInitial; //used to encapsulate the positions with a counter to output
    positionsAndCounter.counter=0;//first initialize to 0

    Position destinies[] = getDestinies(inputMatrix); //get destinies


    TransitionState firstTransitionState = new TransitionState();
    firstTransitionState.positionA=robotInitial[0];
    firstTransitionState.positionB=robotInitial[1];

    transitionStatesArray.add(firstTransitionState);

    //mark transition used , if the transition is new, it should be queued

    queue.add(positionsAndCounter);

    String [] movement =  {"forward", "counter", "clock"}; 
    //possible movements inside inputMatrix


    outer: while (!queue.isEmpty()){ //while queue is not empty

         PositionsAndCounter v= queue.poll(); //dequeue an item from Q into V

         for(int k = 0; k<3; k++){ //for each edge e incident on v in Graph:

            Position[] newRobotPositions = getNewRobotPositions(v.positionPair[0], v.positionPair[1], movement[k], inputMatrix);

            TransitionState newTransitionState = new TransitionState();
            newTransitionState.positionA=newRobotPositions[0];
            newTransitionState.positionB=newRobotPositions[1];

            if(!transitionStatesArray.contains(newTransitionState)){  //if the transition state is new add and enqueue new robot positions

                 transitionStatesArray.add(newTransitionState);

                   //if transition is new then queue
                 PositionsAndCounter newPositionsAndCounter = new PositionsAndCounter();
                 newPositionsAndCounter.positionPair=newRobotPositions;
                 newPositionsAndCounter.counter = v.counter +1;


                  queue.add(newPositionsAndCounter);


             }


             inputMatrix[v.positionPair[0].i][v.positionPair[1].j]='.'; 
             inputMatrix[v.positionPair[1].i][v.positionPair[1].j]='.';

             //inputMatrix[v[0].i][v[0].j]='.'; // mark old position of robot 1 with .
             //inputMatrix[v[1].i][v[1].j]='.'; // mark old position of robot 2 with .

             //update new robot positions
             inputMatrix[newRobotPositions[0].i][newRobotPositions[0].j]= newRobotPositions[0].orientation;
             inputMatrix[newRobotPositions[1].i][newRobotPositions[1].j]= newRobotPositions[1].orientation;


             //check if solution has been found
                   if
                   (
                   ((destinies[0].i==newRobotPositions[0].i)&&(destinies[0].j==newRobotPositions[0].j) //robot in 0 arrived to destiny
                   || (destinies[1].i==newRobotPositions[0].i)&&(destinies[1].j==newRobotPositions[0].j))// in 0 or 1
                        &&                                                                                                      //and 
                  ((destinies[0].i==newRobotPositions[1].i)&&(destinies[0].j==newRobotPositions[1].j) //robot in 1 arrived to destiny
                  || (destinies[1].i==newRobotPositions[0].i)&&(destinies[1].j==newRobotPositions[0].j))//in 0 or 1

                   ) //end if
                   {

                      System.out.println("robots arrived at destinies");
                      System.out.println("robot 1, starting at " + robotInitial[0].i + "," + robotInitial[0].j
                               + " is in " + newRobotPositions[0].i + ","+ newRobotPositions[0].j);
                      System.out.println("robot 2, starting at " + robotInitial[1].i + "," + robotInitial[1].j
                               + " is in " + newRobotPositions[1].i + ","+ newRobotPositions[1].j);

                     System.out.println("movements: " + (v.counter));

                     return;
                     //break outer;

                   }


                }

            }

            System.out.println("robots can never arrive at their destinies");
            System.out.println(-1);


    }


static void printInputMatrix(char [][] inputMatrix){


    for (int i=0; i<inputMatrix[0].length;i++)
        for(int j=0; j<inputMatrix[0].length;j++)
        {

            System.out.print(" "+inputMatrix[i][j]+" ");
            if(j==inputMatrix[0].length-1){System.out.println("");}

        }


}





    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//        System.out.println("Test transition checker");
//        Position p1 = new Position();
//        p1.i=1;
//        p1.j=1;
//        p1.orientation='N';
//        Position p2 = new Position();
//        p2.i=1;
//        p2.j=2;
//        p2.orientation='N';
//        Position p3 = new Position();
//        p3.i=1;
//        p3.j=1;
//        p3.orientation='N';
//        Position p4 = new Position();
//        p4.i=1;
//        p4.j=1;
//        p4.orientation='N';
//
//        TransitionState transitionChecker1 = new TransitionState();
//        transitionChecker1.positionA=p1;
//        transitionChecker1.positionB=p2;
//
//        TransitionState transitionChecker2 = new TransitionState();
//        transitionChecker2.positionA=p1;
//        transitionChecker2.positionB=p2;
//
//
//        ArrayList<TransitionState> arrayTransitions = new ArrayList<TransitionState>();
//        arrayTransitions.add(transitionChecker1);
//        System.out.println("Test contains? " + arrayTransitions.contains(transitionChecker2));




        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("input.txt")));

        char [][] inputMatrix;

        String line;
        char [] lineAsCharArray;
        int matrixSize;

        while(true){

            line = br.readLine();
            matrixSize=Integer.parseInt(line);

            inputMatrix = new char [matrixSize][matrixSize];

            if (matrixSize==0){  // end outer looping
                break;
            }

            else { //begin inner looping

                for (int i=0; i<matrixSize; i++){

                    line = br.readLine();
                    inputMatrix[i] =line.toCharArray();

                }

                //matrix loaded

                BFS(inputMatrix);

            }


        }

    }

}

class PositionsAndCounter {

    Position[] positionPair;
    int counter;

    PositionsAndCounter() {
        positionPair = new Position[2];
        counter=0;

    }
}
```

**Problems:** 
**1)** On the first input.txt file, it finds 9 movements to find the solution of the first course (when they should be 8) and 6 to find the solution of the second course (when it should be 3) though it correctly prints out -1 for the last (impossible) course configuration.

**2)** On the second input.txt file, professor says it should print -1 and -1 for the to first courses, though my program finds a plaussible solution for the second case and a bizarre one for the first (this is where I think a more experienced debugger could help, I'm at a loss tracking the reason for the displaced destiny output on the first case). Are the outputs proposed by my professor right? My algorithm is also getting stuck on that case where 46 should be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are 2 careless copy and paste problems causes the code not working, 
1, in the clockwise turning part:

```
        if (oldR2Pos.orientation == 'E') {

            newR2Pos.orientation = 'O';

        }
```

This is wrong... it should be a direct copy and paste from the above block

```
        if (oldR2Pos.orientation == 'E') {

            newR2Pos.orientation = 'S';
        }
```

Yet you missed it.

Another problem is actually in the end condition testing block

```
     //check if solution has been found
           if
           (
           ((destinies[0].i==newRobotPositions[0].i)&&(destinies[0].j==newRobotPositions[0].j) //robot in 0 arrived to destiny
           || (destinies[1].i==newRobotPositions[0].i)&&(destinies[1].j==newRobotPositions[0].j))// in 0 or 1
                &&                                                                                                      //and 
          ((destinies[0].i==newRobotPositions[1].i)&&(destinies[0].j==newRobotPositions[1].j) //robot in 1 arrived to destiny
          || **(destinies[1].i==newRobotPositions[0].i)&&(destinies[1].j==newRobotPositions[0].j)**)//in 0 or 1

           ) //end if
```

The last part (code highlighted) should be

```
(destinies[1].i==newRobotPositions[1].i)&&(destinies[1].j==newRobotPositions[1].j)
```

It is obviously an copy and paste but forget to change error. The logic is a little bit hard to understand, but works,

(A in X or B in Y) and (A in Y or B in X)

Although it is the same (logically not exactly the same but it some how works for your case as A and B cannot occupy the same location), it is much clearer if you use

(A in X and B in Y) or (A in Y and B in X)

Apart from the fatal errors stated above, your program has a few other issues need to addressed.It looks like you are a university student taking Computer science, please, read the given source code before coding: TransistionState class is not used at all but you created your own PositionsAndCounter, turning logic is implemented twice, if you didn't rewrite the turning code, and use the one given, you won't commit problem 1.... If I were your professor, i may fail you on that. Plan your solution well before hitting the keyboard, and make sure your code is clear and readable as plan english, if you stare at your source code for 5 min and cannot figure out what the block of code is for, may be you didn't structure it correctly.

The listing below is an example solution for your question:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class DualRobot {

    public enum Orientation{
        E(1, 0), S(0, 1), O(-1, 0), N(0, -1);

        public final int dx, dy;
        private Orientation(int dx, int dy){
            this.dx = dx;
            this.dy = dy;
        }

        public Orientation left(){
            return Orientation.values()[(this.ordinal() + 3) % 4];
        }

        public Orientation right(){
            return Orientation.values()[(this.ordinal() + 1) % 4];
        }

        public static Orientation valueOf(char c){
            for(Orientation o : Orientation.values()){
                if(o.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("" + c)) return o;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public enum Action {FORWARD, COUNTER_CLOCKWISE, CLOCKWISE}; // F: forward, L: Counter clockwise, R: clockwise

    private static class Robot{
        Point position;
        Orientation orientation;

        public Robot(Robot r){
            this.position = new Point(r.position);
            this.orientation = r.orientation;
        }
        public Robot(int x, int y, Orientation orientation){
            this.position = new Point(x, y);
            this.orientation = orientation;
        }

        public void move(Action action, char[][] map){
            switch (action) {
            case FORWARD:
                Point nextPosition = new Point(position);
                nextPosition.translate(orientation.dx, orientation.dy);
                if(isValidPosition(nextPosition, map)) position = nextPosition;
                break;
            case COUNTER_CLOCKWISE:
                this.orientation = this.orientation.left();
                break;
            case CLOCKWISE:
                this.orientation = this.orientation.right();
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof Robot) {
                Robot r = (Robot) obj;
                return r.position.equals(this.position) && r.orientation == this.orientation;
            }
            return super.equals(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return orientation.ordinal() + position.x * 10 + position.y * 1000;
        }

        private boolean isValidPosition(Point p, char[][] map){
            return p.x >= 0 && p.x < map[0].length 
                && p.y >= 0 && p.y < map.length
                && map[p.y][p.x] != '*';
        }
    }

    private static class State{
        private Robot a, b;
        private int counter;

        public State(Robot a, Robot b, int counter) {
            this.a = new Robot(a);
            this.b = new Robot(b);
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        public List<State> nextStates(char[][] map){
            List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();
            for(Action action : Action.values()){
                State s = new State(this.a, this.b, this.counter + 1);
                s.a.move(action, map);
                s.b.move(action, map);
                if(!s.a.position.equals(s.b.position)){ // Test for collision
                    states.add(s);
                }
            }
            return states;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof State) {
                State state = (State) obj; // Consider the state to be the same if the 2 robots are at identical location and orientation
                return (this.a.equals(state.a) && this.b.equals(state.b))
                    || (this.a.equals(state.b) && this.b.equals(state.a));
            }
            return super.equals(obj);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            // The quality of this hashCode can affect the program's speed
            // Multiply is transitive, so if you swap a and b, the hashcode is the same
            return a.hashCode() * b.hashCode();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        int size;

        while((size = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine())) > 0){
            // Load the data;
            char[][] map = new char[size][size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                map[i] = input.readLine().toCharArray();
            }

            // Construct initial state
            List<Robot> robots = new ArrayList<Robot>();
            List<Point> destinations = new ArrayList<Point>();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++){
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j ++){
                    Orientation orientation = Orientation.valueOf(map[i][j]);
                    if(orientation != null){
                        robots.add(new Robot(j, i, orientation));
                    }else if(map[i][j] == 'D'){
                        destinations.add(new Point(j, i));
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(BFSSearch(map, new State(robots.get(0), robots.get(1), 0), destinations));

        }

    }

    private static int BFSSearch(char[][] map, State initialState, List<Point> destinations) throws IOException{
        List<State> queue = new LinkedList<State>(); // Array list is slightly more efficient
        queue.add(initialState); // Initial state
        Map<State, Boolean> testedStates = new HashMap<State, Boolean>();
        while(queue.size() > 0){
            State currentState = queue.remove(0);
            if(testedStates.containsKey(currentState)) continue;

            // Testing for end condition
            if((currentState.a.position.equals(destinations.get(0)) && currentState.b.position.equals(destinations.get(1)))
            || (currentState.a.position.equals(destinations.get(1)) && currentState.b.position.equals(destinations.get(0)))){
                return currentState.counter;
            }
            testedStates.put(currentState, true);
            queue.addAll(currentState.nextStates(map));
        }
        return -1;
    }   
}
```

This program spit out the final answer in around 10 seconds.

The main difference is I used an hash table to store the tested states to improve the speed, thus the quality of the hash function would have an effect on the speed.

Recommended reading: hash table, DRY principle.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time at looking at the code. This code was all written by me. In my college (I study at Universidad Central de Venezuela) we're never given partial projects to build up, I'm surprised to hear that's the methodology elsewhere. The two omissions you pinpointed are making the code run correctly on all cases except the last one of the 2nd input file, where my algorithm gets stuck. I'm wondering what's happening there.

Comment: Your program didn't hang, in fact, it just take very long time to run. 1. A 25*25 matrix with about 70% space would give a single robot 25*25*0.7*4 = 1750 different states, and combination of 2 robots would be roughly 1750*1750 = 3 million different states.

Comment: 2. Looking at the algorithm for searching of past status, you basically iterated through all the past states, which means the searching has an O(n) running upper bound, combining the BFS on the 3million states, it is O(n^2), which means, your program would just start to run slower and slower when the size of the matrix increase.

Comment: The sample given probably would run for a few hour, but there is room for improvement. As the question asking for BFS, so you cannot work on that part to much, but the searching in past states part can be improved: you can use an hash table for past states, the search time is close to O(1), or keep the past states in an sorted array use binary search for it which is O(log(n)).